# Is it common to use contractions with names

Tags: pronunciation, contractions

Are contractions commonly used with names in informal speech?

for example

1. Bob'll be here soon
2. Bill'll be here too
3. Mary'd find your joke amusing

And also, I find some contractions difficult to pronounce with names and use the full form instead. Is it actually not that hard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, it's common to use (some) contractions with proper nouns. Native speakers use them all the time. In your first two examples, the **'ll** is usually pronounced **uhl** ([əl]). Also, you *don't have to* use contractions if you find them difficult to pronounce. Both the contracted and uncontracted forms are correct. And no, it's not hard for native speakers but it might be for non-natives at first.

Here are some examples from [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/contractions) [emphasis mine]:

- > My **sister’s** got married. = My sister **has** got married.
- > **John’ll** be very happy. = John **will** be very happy.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have another question: how to pronounce 'Bill'll'? I just say 'Billlll'. Should I make a pause between 'Bill' and " 'll "?

Comment: @adik: Bill'll is pronounced **Billuhl**. No, there isn't any pause between Bill and 'll. (The *uh* is the schwa sound [ə].)